# django-static files in production

Tags: python, django, heroku, static

i cant seem to solve the issue of static files in production. I understand that the host service should take care of static files in production when debug is off, but it for some reason heroku fails to do it.
ive installed whitenoise as instructed in Django, and it did solve a different problem I had when tring to push to heroku. but still when I turn debug false static files stop working. this is my settings on production:
    import os
    from django.conf import settings

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

DATABASES= settings.DATABASES

# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

SHARE_URL = "https://fast-reaches-2219.herokuapp.com/?ref="
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

and the wsgi.py file:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "test_project.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)

try:
    from dj_static import Cling

    application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
except:
    pass
```

Comment: You don't need both WhiteNoise and Cling; they're alternatives.

Comment: Plus,  you really shouldn't silently catch exceptions. Is something going wrong within that try/except? We'll *never know*. Don't do that.

Comment: thank you , i uninstalled whitenoise, and researched more about how cling works, apperently my static root wasnt configured correctly at the settings. problem solved :)